# False 404 from Django test?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm having trouble with testing my Django app.  I can load a page in the browser just fine, but my test code returns 404.

This test returns False:

```
def test_item(self):
    response = self.client.get('/items/1/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

If I stick a print line in there somewhere...

```
print(response)
```

... it returns the full HTML page, as expected:

```
Vary: Accept-Language, Cookie
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en

<!DOCTYPE html>
... 
</html>
```

Which looks good (should be 200) to me.  But it's not:

```
print(response.status_code)
```

...returns 404

What am I missing?

---

**Versions**

Django 1.6, Python 2.7.6

**URL**

```
http://localhost:8000/items/1/
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r"^(?P<item_id>[0-9]+/?)/$", "item.views.item_by_id",),
    )
```

**views.py**

```
def item_by_id(request, item_id):
    try:
        item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
    except Item.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render(request, 'item.html', {'item': item})
```

Comment: Is that an error in your first code block? It shows you testing the `status_code` of `resp_1`, but it should be testing `response`.

Comment: yep, sorry; artifact from copy/paste.  I updated my question. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add view code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have an `item_id` that matches your `url` (i.e., there's no "1" in your database). In your view, it's trying to get the `Item` but it's raising an exception, thus returning an `HTTP404`. The test and view is working exactly as it should.

Unit tests create a new (empty) database, so any `Items` you have in your regular database won't appear. You'll need to create an `Item` within your test file with the `item_id` that you're checking.

Sample:

```
def test_item(self):
    Item.objects.create(name="Item1") # Note you may need to edit the fields based on your model

    response = self.client.get('/items/1/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Comment: Yep, still wrapping my head around some core Django concepts.  Thanks very much.